# Update multiple columns conditionally

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Good Day! I'm currently having trouble in updating my database. I'm coding in c#.net and using SQL server.

My problem is that I'm trying to update multiple columns conditionally. Here's my code:

```
"Update Eureka Set Milestone1 = Case When Milestone1 = '" + araw.Text + "' then Milestone_status = '" + m1 + "' End, Milestone2 = When Milestone2 = '" + araw.Text + "' then Milestone_status = '" + m2 + "' End, Milestone3 = When Milestone3 = '" + araw.Text + "' Then Milestone_status = '" + m3 + "' End, Milestone4 = When Milestone4 = '" + araw.Text + "' Then Milestone_status = '" + m4 + "' End, Milestone5 = When Milestone5 = '" + araw.Text + "' Then Milestone_status = '" + m5 + "' End Where Eureka_id = '" + eid.Text + "'"
```

If Milestone1 is equal to today's date (araw.text) then the milestone status will be changed. If not, the milestone_status won't be changed. Then the same goes for milestone2 to milestone5.

My code is SQL statement is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SQL Injection possible. Use prepared statement/parameter binding.

Comment: thanks for the reminder. Once my SQL statement works, I'll use parameters on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try;

```
Update Eureka 
Set Milestone_status = 
    Case 
        When Milestone1 = @araw_Text then @m1
        when Milestone2 = @araw_Text then @m2
        when Milestone3 = @araw_Text then @m3
        when Milestone4 = @araw_Text then @m4
        when Milestone5 = @araw_Text then @m5
        else Milestone_status
    end
Where Eureka_id = @eid_Text
```

This will update 
`Milestone_status` with `m1`, if `Milestone1 = araw.Text`
`Milestone_status` with `m2`, if `Milestone2 = araw.Text`
`Milestone_status` with `m3`, if `Milestone3 = araw.Text`....

If no condition is satisfied then `Milestone_status` will not be modified

Comment: Hi, I've tried your code but it is still not working. I've already added parameters. I think the statement is correct but it is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

Taking it out of the C# for a moment and considering it as a SQL statement alone, and just looking at milestone1 for simplicity, your SQL would have to be something like:

```
UPDATE Eureka
   SET milestone_status = 
      CASE WHEN milestone1 = @todays_date then @m1
      ELSE milestone_status
      END
```

i.e. if milestone1 is todays date then set milestone_status to @m1, else set it to itself (i.e. don't change it).

SQL docs has several good examples on use of the CASE syntax, might be worth reviewing too for clarity: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Your CASE statement is worng syntax:

```
Update Eureka 
Set Milestone1 = Case When Milestone1 = 'araw.Text' then Milestone_status = 'm1' End
,   Milestone2 = When Milestone2 = 'araw.Text' then Milestone_status = 'm2' End
,   Milestone3 = When Milestone3 = 'araw.Text' Then Milestone_status = 'm3' End
,   Milestone4 = When Milestone4 = 'araw.Text' Then Milestone_status = 'm4' End
,   Milestone5 = When Milestone5 = 'araw.Text' Then Milestone_status = 'm5' End 
Where Eureka_id = 'eid.Text'
```

The proper syntax have to be like

```
CASE expression

   WHEN value_1 THEN result_1
   WHEN value_2 THEN result_2
   ...
   WHEN value_n THEN result_n

   ELSE result

END
```

In your case you can use nested CASE to check each Milestone(Milestone1,Milestone2,..)

```
"Update Eureka
set Milestone_status = case when Milestone1 = '" + araw.Text + "' then '" + m1 + "' else 
                         case when Milestone2 = '" + araw.Text + "' then '" + m2 + "' else
                           case when Milestone3 = '" + araw.Text + "' then '" + m3 + "' else
                             case when Milestone4 = '" + araw.Text + "' then '" + m4 + "' else
                               case when Milestone5 = '" + araw.Text + "' then '" + m5 + "' else Milestone_status end
                              end
                            end                              
                          end
                        end
Where Eureka_id = '" + eid.Text + "'"
```

Comment: Would you kindly explain what exactly you've changed so others can benefit from your answer

Comment: I've tried your code but the statement is still not working. I don't know why. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey, no need to be sarcastic here. I'm trying to learn. By the way my question is not updated so you won't be able to see the code that I'm currently trying. Thanks for your help though.